# $\forall g\in L^2(\Omega)$ exists $g_n\in H_0^1(\Omega)$ and $\epsilon>0$ s.t $g_n(x)\to g(x),\,a.e$ and $|g_n(x)|\leq |g(x)|+\epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^d$ ($d=2,3$) is a bounded Lipschitz domain.

> **Question:**
>   Is it true that for each function $g(x)\in L^2(\Omega)$ one can find a sequence $\{g_n\}_1^\infty$ of $H_0^1(\Omega)$ functions such that $g_n(x)\to g(x),\,a.e$ in $\Omega$ and $|g_n(x)|\leq |g(x)|+\epsilon,\,a.e,\,\forall n\ge 1$ for some $\epsilon>0$ ?

In the case when $g\in L^\infty(\Omega)$ and $m:=\|g\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)}$, then also $g\in L^p(\Omega),\,1\leq p<\infty$ so there is $g_n\in C_0^\infty(\Omega)$ s.t $g_n\to g$ in $L^p(\Omega)$ and from it we can extract a subsequence $g_{n_k}(x)\to g(x),\,a.e$. Finally, we construct the smooth function $\varphi:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ s.t $\varphi(t)=t,\,|t|\leq m+1$, $\varphi(t)=m+2,\,t>m+2$, $\varphi(t)=-m-2,\,t<-m-2$ and take the functions $\varphi\circ g_{n_k}$. These functions satisfy $\varphi\circ g_{n_k}(x)\to g(x),\,a.e$ and $|\varphi\circ g_{n_k}(x)|\leq m+2$.

**Remark:** It is easy to show (see for example Th. 4.9 in Brezis' book *Functional Analysis*) that for $g_n\to g$ in $L^p(\Omega)$ there exists a subsequence $g_{n_k}$ s.t $g_{n_k}(x)\to g(x),\,a.e$ and $|g_{n_k}(x)|\leq h(x)$ for some $h\in L^p(\Omega)$. As $C_0^\infty(\Omega)\subset H_0^1(\Omega)$ is dense in $L^2(\Omega)$ we can find $g_n\to g$ in $L^2(\Omega)$ and apply Th. 4.9, but then we get only $|g_{n_k}(x)|\leq h(x)$

Comment: I doubt $|g_n(x)|\leq |g(x)|+\epsilon$ could be true. Let $g$ be the characteristic function of a fat Cantor set. The Sobolev functions have strong quasi-continuity properties (so-called p-quasicontinuous representative). I think that having $g_n\le \epsilon$ outside of the Cantor set will force $g_n\le \epsilon$ on most of the Cantor set too.

Comment: @404 Fisrt, thanks for the response. But in this example, $g\in L^\infty$ and then we can construct $g_n(x)\in C_0^\infty\to g(x),\, a.e$ and such that $|g_n(x)|\leq \|g\|_{L^\infty}+2$ as in the text below the remark in my post. So in this case, $\epsilon$ would be $\|g\|_\infty+2$ or something like this.

Comment: I see, $\epsilon$ does not have to be small. Then the scenario to consider is when $g$ is unbounded. Maybe $g=0$ on the Cantor set $C$ and $g(x) = -\operatorname{dist}(x,C)^{-p}$ elsewhere, where $p>0$ is just small enough to ensure $g\in L^2$. Again, the quasicontinuity is difficult to reconcile with such behavior.

Comment: @404 Your example might turn to be fruitful, but I can not show a contradiction. What I checked is that the exponent $p$ should be less than $1/4$ to ensure that $g\in L^2([0,1])$. Would you try to elaborate on your idea ?

Comment: I mean $p<1/4$ is particularly for the Smith-Volterra-Cantor set. Also I tried applying Egorov's theorem but again without  success.